# Workflow Task List

Tags: tasks

I am working on a custom workflow and I'm unable to figure out how to populate the "task" list with information captured on the workflow initiation form.  I added a custom field to the initiation form, but am unable to view it on the task list. I've been able to add information from the approval form but not the initiation form. Any ideas?

Also, in general I don't see anywhere in SharePoint designer where the fields that will be sent to the "task" list can be changed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The workflow tasks are created on SharePoint Designer, but for the columns to be seen this has to be done through your actual SharePoint site and SharePoint Designer.

1. in SharePoint Designer click on the workflow information’s page for the workflow you created. On the right hand where it says "Setting" create/select a TASK LIST, this is where the information captured from your tasks will go.
2. Once you have created that go to that list on your SharePoint site on the top navigation bar select "LIST" and click on "Modify View"
3. In "Modify View" click the checks next to the task name , now when you save and the next workflow will show the information.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  On the settings page I see Start Options and Forms, but nothing about creating/selecting a task list.

Comment: I've seen the create/select task list you refer to on-line, but it's not there for my version.  Also, it appears this is where you can choose the list but what about the specific fields for the task list?  Can those be edited?

Comment: Yes those can be edited because normally you would attach the workflow to a task list , and in SharePoint (the site itself) you can modify the columns (step 3) and the tasks show up with whatever name you gave them in the workflow in SharePoint Desighner to the SharePoint Site.